# CSS animation with frame prevent :hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, frame

I'm doing a CSS `animation` with a background transition, and I would like a different background for the :hover.
But it doesn't work: when I put my cursor hover the div, the animation is still playing but the hover state is not considered.

When I remove the animation, it works perfectly.

Do you have any idea?

thanks

```
.loaderGif{
            width: 465px;
            height: 465px; 
            background: url('../images/loader01.png');
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-animation: animLoader 4s infinite;
            animation:         animLoader 4s infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes animLoader {
              0%   { background: url('../images/loader01.png'); }
              50% { background: url('../images/loader02.png'); }
              100% { background: url('../images/loader01.png'); }
            }

.loaderGif:hover{
                background: url('../images/loaderBlack.gif');
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS declarations in the animation overwrite other declarations during the animation:

"CSS Animations affect computed property values. During the execution of an animation, the computed value for a property is controlled by the animation. This overrides the value specified in the normal styling system. Animations override all normal rules, but are overriden by !important rules." - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/

Once the animation finishes, the .loaderGif:hover will be active, though in case it never will because the animation is infinite.

To fix your issue, change your code to

```
.loaderGif:hover{              
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation:         none;
    background: url('../images/loaderBlack.gif');
}
```